# How to make fading in background-color transition to bootstrap page using CSS?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, transition, background-color, css-animations

I have page A, which bg-color is for ex. #fff. Now when I click a link and proceed to page B, the bg-color is
 `.body {background-color: #007F46;}`

As you might guess, the change from white to this greenish color is quite sudden. Is there any way to make a transition-kind thing that when my page loads, it changes the color automatically from #fff to #color-here at duration X. Doesn't matter if it's accomplished by CSS or jquery.

There is all the :hover stuff, but I don't think that it is very convenient, as my page B might be in a tab of the browser and then every time when you open the that, the color will change.

So in nutshell - anyone have a solution for "page loads" -> "bg-color is white" -> "bg-color changes to green in .5s". -> end of story, no changing again until I reload the page/restart browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery/CSS solution

CSS: Add a class `loaded` that has the background color you want as the bg color

```
body {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

body.loaded {
   background-color: green;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

On document ready, add the class `loaded` to your body

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("loaded");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R3jjM/

Comment: Just the thing! Thank you so much. Too bad that background-image is not "fadeable"... even when I move the bg-img CSS to body.loaded, my background slides from left of the screen. Kind of cool though... anyway this does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.site-wrapper-inner')
        .css({"opacity":0})   
        .delay(200)           
        .css({"opacity":1});  
});
```

This may result in a flicker but shouldn't be too bad. Basically page loads it gets hidden and then faded back in, in time for the user to notice it

EDIT: To make use of this you will need the following

this should go under your bootstrap.js tag:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

So it ends up looking something like:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#id_to_fade_in')
            .css({"opacity":0})   
            .delay(200)           
            .css({"opacity":1});  
    });
</script>
```

That should be enough to get you started

Comment: How I use this? Add to bootstrap.js? EDIT: oh and sounds not too likely to be a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Ah, sorry thought you were familiar with jquery, hang on will edit post.

Comment: There is already <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script> included in the bootstrap. Will I copy the code that u posted to the first line of bootstrap.js file or to the bottom of the page?

Comment: It needs it own script tag.

Comment: I am so sorry, but just don't get this one... if it is any help, perhaps you could take a look when you can and say what I did wrong.

http://www.kolumbus.fi/kadn/kukapaatti/cover.html

Sites name is cover.html and the code you posted is at the bottom of the html page.

Comment: is cover-container the div you want to fade in?

Comment: Well... actuallu the whole site. I think it includes "site-wrapper" and everything in it...

Here is an updated version of the page: http://www.kukapaatti.fi

Comment: try updated code and don't forget to make as answer if it solves your problem please